# REST: what's the name for the HTTP verb and endpoint?

Tags: rest, terminology

Given this:

```
GET /users
```

`/users` is called `endpoint` in REST terminology.

How do you call the whole `GET /users` (verb + endpoint) instead? I hope there is one word for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably won't like this answer, but here it is anyway: REST does not use the terminology "endpoint" at all. You can check Fielding's thesis yourself: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm - open the PDF and search for "endpoint".

Fumanchu's answer is probably the closest you get: "/Users" is a relative path and can be used as the Request-URI in the Request-Line as per the 2616 HTTP spec.

In a web API documentation I would probably call "/Users" an "Endpoint" reference as you do, and "GET /Users" would be an "Operation". Maybe you can get some inspiration here: https://nhs.3scale.net/docs

Comment: I actually liked your answer very much :)

Answer (score 5):

The [API Bluprint Language Specification](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#ResourceActionSection) refers to the HTTP method, when applied to a resource, as a [resource action](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#ResourceActionSection).  This name seems to be consistent with the terminology in [section 5.2.1.2 Representations, of Fielding's dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_2).

Answer (score 2):

RFC 2616 (the HTTP spec) calls the first line of a request the "Request-Line". It consists of the method, Request-URI, and version. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1 for complete details.

Comment: Close...however we don't want the HTTP version in the mix.

Answer (score 2):

We call it 'resource operation'

Basically, you are mapping your operations like

- Create a new user
- Get User info
- Update User info
- Remove user

to "HTTP verb + Resource"

- POST /user/
- GET /user/
- PUT /user/
- DELETE /user/