# What do you call the action done for a HTTP method at a REST resource

Tags: rest, http, uri

What do you call a HTTP method path combo in HTTP REST? For example `GET /users` or `POST /users`. What do you call that specific method-resource tuple? HTTP function? endpoint? action?

EDIT:
Looking for a more definitive answer than [REST: what's the name for the HTTP verb and endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588318/rest-whats-the-name-for-the-http-verb-and-endpoint) if possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588318/rest-whats-the-name-for-the-http-verb-and-endpoint

Comment: @Ness this question is indeed a duplicate of that one. However the selected answer there is not very definitive. Lets shake the tree here for a bit and see if any better answers come up before deferring to that one.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP function

No, I've never heard that.

> endpoint

That has a [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)y ring to it, I would not use it.

> action

That sounds like [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). Doing RPC and calling it REST is plain wrong.

I can think of nothing better than "using a HTTP method on a resource".

Answer (score 0):

I've generally referred to it as a "REST method" or "resource method" as opposed to HTTP X because often times the HTTP actions are overloaded -- for instance, GET can be for a specific resource or to index based on query parameters. Thus in GET /users would be "users resource method" or "show on user resource". REST is a layer above HTTP and thus, leaving it out of your vocabulary when discussing REST may make it far simpler for discussion.

I also tend to dissociate the HTTP method (GET/POST etc) with the underlying function (show, index, create, update.) This way it's far easier to reuse HTTP the verbs and have clarity when speaking about the actions.